# A homeomorphic to B implies $\pi_1(A)$ isomorphic to $\pi_1(B)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to prove what is stated from above. I feel like it should just follow from the definition of the fundamental group, but I'm not entirely sure where to go from there (sorry if I'm missing something obvious!).

Comment: $\pi_2(B)$? The second homotopy group of $B$?

Comment: I presume you mean $\pi_1(B)$?

Comment: For the converse see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706514/isomorphic-fundamental-groups-result-in-homeomorphism).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made an error, it was supposed to be $\pi_2$. I have edited it now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You really need $A$ and $B$ to be path-connected for this question to make sense. Finicky topologists would write $\pi_1(A,a)$ rather than $\pi_1(A)$ where $a\in A$ is a base-point.

Comment: Use functoriality: functoriality tells us that $h_*$ is an isomorphism, since $id_*=(hh^{-1})_*=h_*h^{-1}_*$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homeomorphic spaces have the same homology groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510189/homeomorphic-spaces-have-the-same-homology-groups)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f : A \to B$ be a continuous map. If $u : [0,1] \to A$ is a loop in $A$, then $f \circ u : [0,1] \to B$ is a loop in $B$. This descends to a map of homotopy groups
$$f_* : \pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(B)$$
defined by $f_*([u]) = [f \circ u]$ for all homotopy classes $[u]$ of loops in $A$.

You should check that $f_*$ is a well-defined group homomorphism, and that when $f$ is a homeomorphism, the map $f_*$ is an isomorphism of groups.